# I can't click form in UIWebView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, click

I am builing an iOS app in which users swipe from left to right to show an UIWebView containing html form and scrollable html element.

However, any click in that UIWebView are like rejected. So I can't click or scroll in it.

How come ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // chat 
   NSString *fullURL = @"http://website.com/chat";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   chat = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
   [chat loadRequest:requestObj];
   chat.frame = CGRectMake(-284, 0, chat.frame.size.width, chat.frame.size.height);

   // move the uiwebview
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer * gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveChat:)];
   // left or right
   [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)|(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];

   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

// handle the swipe gesture
- (void)moveChat:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    [self displayHideChat];
}

// display chat uiwebview
- (void)displayHideChat
{
    if (chatOpened)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x  - 272,
                                     self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                     self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x  + 272,
                                     self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                     self.view.frame.size.height );
    }

    chatOpened = !chatOpened;
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the userInteractionEnabled to on (YES). webview.userInteractionEnabled = YES. or try setting the webView delegate like this: webView.delegate = self;

Comment: yes, already checked.

Comment: What about trying this: `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
   return YES;
}`

Comment: check that there isn't any view with clear color, show me your code, I ll try to help

Comment: edited : code added. @troop231, still not working.

Comment: Is there other code you omitted? I can't see anything going on here

Comment: something like what ? I don't think. Maybe the UIWebView setting : http://cl.ly/image/01380k1T2w3X